# Adobe Acrobat Reader crashing after page 12 with PdfTeX

Tags: pdftex, texstudio, acrobat

I am a beginner to LaTeX and a teacher brought this issue to my attention. I've been using TeXstudio as my editor with the PdfTeX compiler.

Essentially what happens is when she (my teacher) opens the document on Acrobat Reader, she's able to add comments on the first 11 pages, then Acrobat Reader crashes on the 12th onwards. I'm honestly unsure of how this is possible but she says it only happens to my documents (and I'm the only one using LaTeX in my class).

I'm not sure what the issue is, I'm currently using the following:

```
%Formattting
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

%Mathematics
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{upgreek}

%Citations
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}

\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption*{Source: {#1}} }
\newcommand{\figref}[1]{Fig. \ref{#1}}

\bibliography{PhysicsIA} 



%Other
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
```

I am aware I have a few redundant packages - I've just been copy pasting my headers between documents for all my school essays (all are the same format).

Comment: This doesn’t reproduce the bug, but why is `\usepackage[]{geometry}` there with no options?

Comment: Does removing the unnecessary packages (`geometry` without options, `gensymb` when you have `\textmicro`, etc. in LaTeX already) solve the issue?

Comment: I'll give these a shot and get back to you @Davislor

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of `citecolor=black, filecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black`, you may want to specify `allcolors=black`.

Comment: The packages look fine. Is there something special on page 12? E.g a graphic,  a new font, links?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the only thing I have on page 12 is a graphic - just a simply png (which I have on previous pages) - as well as a table